# What could cause an ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE for a PostToConnectionCommand in typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am writing a function that uses the PostToConnectionCommand to send a websocket message in typescript. The function looks like this

```
async function sendMessageToClient(connectionId: string, payload) {
  try {
    console.log('Sending message to a connection', connectionId)

    const apiGatewayManagementApi = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({
      apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
      endpoint: `https://${apiId}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${stage}`
    });

    console.log("apiId", apiId, "stage", stage, "payload", payload);
    

    const postToConnectionCommand = new PostToConnectionCommand({
      ConnectionId: connectionId,
      Data: payload
    });
    console.log("postToconnection command", postToConnectionCommand);
    

    const response = (await apiGatewayManagementApi.send(postToConnectionCommand));
    // Error is thrown at the line above
    console.log("response", response);
    

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed to send message', JSON.stringify(err))
    if (err.statusCode === 410) {
      console.log('Stale connection')

      await deleteItem(connectionsTable, connectionId)
    }
  }

}
```

I am trying to use v3 sdk (aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi). I keep getting this error:

```
{
    "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE",
    "$metadata": {
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    }
}
```

I believe typescript would have caught type errors. Any one got any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from the node_modules. The payload was meant to be a string. In `.\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-apigatewaymanagementapi\dist-types\models\models_0.d.ts`, In the two types defined for the parameters none of them were string which causes the error[image: node_modules]